# How to do ES Moving Avearge Prediction with Logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am using Elasticsearch 2.3.2, and Logstash 2.3.3. I have found from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-movavg-aggregation.html which states that moving average can do predictions. **I know it is possible to only make query in ES, but I am not sure how should I do that with logstash**. 
I have a logstash file which reads a csv log file storing CPU usage for every 15 seconds. Should I just include the following into the logstash output json file for the related index as an output mapping?

```
{
    "the_movavg":{
        "moving_avg":{
            "buckets_path": "the_sum",
            "window" : 30,
            "model" : "holt_winters",
            "settings" : {
                "type" : "mult",
                "alpha" : 0.5,
                "beta" : 0.5,
                "gamma" : 0.5,
                "period" : 7,
                "pad" : true
            }
        }
}
```

This is my json file for logstash

```
{
  "template" : "linux_cpu-*",
  "settings" : {
    "index.refresh_interval" : "5s"
  },
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
      "_all" : {"enabled" : true, "omit_norms" : true},
      "dynamic_templates" : [ {
        "message_field" : {
          "match" : "message",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
            "fielddata" : { "format" : "disabled" }
          }
        }
      }, {
        "string_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "string", "index" : "analyzed", "omit_norms" : true,
            "fielddata" : { "format" : "disabled" },
            "fields" : {
              "raw" : {"type": "string", "index" : "not_analyzed", "ignore_above" : 256}
            }
          }
        }
      } ],
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp": { "type": "date" },
        "@version": { "type": "string", "index": "not_analyzed" },
        "geoip"  : {
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties" : {
            "ip": { "type": "ip" },
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" },
            "latitude" : { "type" : "float" },
            "longitude" : { "type" : "float" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And is it possible to have it as a graph as to be shown in Kibana?

Comment: With Logstash you only index data, everything else is done on Elasticsearch side.

Comment: Then is it possible that I made some query in ES and make charts based on my ES query?